# React reusing a component with different state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React and trying to write my first app to get a better understanding.

What I'm trying to build is a simple time tracking tool where the user can start and stop a work timer.

Here you can see the design I came up with:
[image]

If the user clicks on the "start" button the working time Timer component should update every second. If the user clicks then on the "take a break" button the timer should stop and instead the break time Timer component should start ticking.

I would like to reuse the Timer component for both working and break timer and just set different states.

I already managed to do this but I don't know if this is a nice way or if this can be improved and make it more generic?

My Tracker component looks like this:

```
class Tracker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            workTime: 0,
            breakTime: 0,
            isRunning: false,
            timerType: 'workTimer'
        }
    }

    startTimer(type) {
        this.setState({
            isRunning: true,
            timerType: type
        });
        this.timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.updateTimer()
        }, 1000);
    }

    stopTimer() {
        this.setState({
            isRunning: false
        });
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
    }

    toggleBreak(type) {
        this.setState({
            timerType: type
        });

        if (!this.state.isRunning && this.state.timerType === 'breakTimer') {
            this.startTimer('breakTimer');
        } else if (this.state.isRunning && this.state.timerType === 'breakTimer') {
            this.stopTimer();
            this.startTimer('workTimer');
        } else {
            this.stopTimer();
            this.startTimer('breakTimer');
        }
    }

    updateTimer() {
        let state = null;

        if (this.state.timerType === 'workTimer') {
            state = {
                workTime: this.state.workTime + 1000
            };
        } else {
            state = {
                breakTime: this.state.breakTime + 1000
            };
        }

        this.setState(state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tracker">
                <Timer time={ this.state.workTime }/>
                <Timer time={ this.state.breakTime }/>
                <TimerControls
                    isRunning={ this.state.isRunning }
                    start={ () => this.startTimer('workTimer') }
                    stop={ () => this.stopTimer() }
                    toggleBreak={ () => this.toggleBreak('breakTimer') }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Controls component:

```
class TimerControls extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const {isRunning, start, stop, toggleBreak} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="tracker__control">
            <button onClick={ start } disabled={ isRunning }>Start</button>
            <button onClick={ toggleBreak }>Break</button>
            <button onClick={ stop } disabled={ !isRunning }>Stop</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Timer component:

```
 class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { time } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="tracker__timer">{ timeFormat(time) }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the timerType conditions?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by generic?

Comment: I´m actually not sure if my implementation is the best way or if there is another way with some react magic which fits better.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be better than that. If you have only 2 types, it could be `isWork` bool instead of `timerType`. Seems like it's already working and good enough, so it's not a kind of problem SO is intended for. Consider posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok thanks for your help and the link 